# Upgrading R from 3.4.4 to latest version on linux mint 19

Tags: r, linux, updates

I know there are a whole bunch of posts related to upgrading R on linux mint but none of those posts have worked for me. I have followed the instructions from this github page:
"https://github.com/duckmayr/install-update-r-on-linux"

When I update (`sudo apt update`) everythign runs smoothly and I see this in one line of the output:

```
Hit:12 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease
```

But when I load R it still remains as version 3.4.4

I've tried removing R and reinstalling it with `sudo apt install r-base` but I encounter this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.1-3bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm running linux mint 19 cinnamon version 3.8.9

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361814/whats-the-difference-between-software-update-and-upgrade  Maybe try apt update, then apt upgrade?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a newer version available? The last time I had a distro based on debian stable, the version of R that I got from the repo was 2 years old.